# How to set a command to switch between two monitors

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xrandr, monitors

My (Linux Mint) PC is connected via Display Port and HDMI to a Monitor and a TV. I want to be able to switch between them, so that the other one is disabled. Are there any commands that can perform this switch? Like some `xrandr` based stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
 xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto
 xrandr --output DP-0 --off
```

adjusting the names?

Comment: To get the names, use `xrandr -q` for a list of displays and possible resolutions. Add `--mode <width>x<height>` for setting the resolution values (matching one of the `-q` possibilities .... or stay with `--auto`). The two lines could be done in one `xrandr`-command with two `--output` arguments.